# How can I get the distribution of length of time in a certain state, while skipping certain states?

Tags: python, pandas, distribution

I am having difficulties formulating the question so I will try to explain it as well as possible.

For a simulation that I am doing I need to determine the distribution of time that a machine is in a certain state given what the next state is going to be. This is the distribution that I am going to sample out of for how my machine functions.

At the same time there are 2 states, **8** and **16** that can be seen as "total system failure". These are the states that I am trying to optimize, so they should not be taken into account for the distributions, so whenever a state goes i.e. 128 - 16 - 1024, I would like to have the total time - time in state 16 (if that makes sense).

As of yet I have the current state, next state and state change as columns in my data frame as well as the datetime as index.

I hope that this explanation made it a bit clearer, if there are any more questions I will gladly answer them.

As an example of what I envision the output to be: Ideally it would be an object in such a form that a distribution plot can be made. From this I would then run and RNG to deduce how long my machine will be in its current state before moving on to another state.

So my machine basically will function like this:

1. It will be put in a running state
2. A sample will be taken out of its distribution (normal, exponential, gausian etc) and that determines how long the machine stays in it's current state.
3. Once the allotted time has passed, a new state will be chosen
4. and the cycle keeps on repeating.

So I would like help with point 2.

Hope this clears it up a bit more.

Here is a reproducible sample of my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CurrentState': {'2022-02-01 00:20:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:21:00': '1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:22:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:23:00': '1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:34:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:35:00': '1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:37:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:42:00': '16',
  '2022-02-01 00:43:00': '8',
  '2022-02-01 00:47:00': '128'},
 'Next_State': {'2022-02-01 00:20:00': '1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:21:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:22:00': '1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:23:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:34:00': '1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:35:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:37:00': '16',
  '2022-02-01 00:42:00': '8',
  '2022-02-01 00:43:00': '128',
  '2022-02-01 00:47:00': '16'},
 'State_Change': {'2022-02-01 00:20:00': '128-1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:21:00': '1024-128',
  '2022-02-01 00:22:00': '128-1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:23:00': '1024-128',
  '2022-02-01 00:34:00': '128-1024',
  '2022-02-01 00:35:00': '1024-128',
  '2022-02-01 00:37:00': '128-16',
  '2022-02-01 00:42:00': '16-8',
  '2022-02-01 00:43:00': '8-128',
  '2022-02-01 00:47:00': '128-16'}})
```

Comment: Can you add a rough example of what you expect the output to look like? It would help as the statement for distribution confuses me. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes of course. I will edit my question.

Comment: @GT1992 do you want the runtime between states 8 or 16 until the next occurrence?
or do you want the time interval in which the machine assumes a certain state?

Comment: @Rafael M R de Rezende I would like the time that the machine is in a certain state barring the 8 or 16 state. So ideally that if there is a state change 128-16 and the next is 16-1024, that it is actually seen as 12-1024 but then minus the time the machine was in state 16.